# Help with button in Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

This might be a dumb question, but I'm honestly at a loss here, and I don't know much about aura components. I have a button I need to add functionality to (make it mark a checkbox in an object) but even when I can see the button in the page, and if I click it, it opens a new page, I can't find a controller, or an actual button.

This is the component and what opens when I click the fifth option, TuitionPaymentCheck.

Any help is a lot of help at this point, thank you!

```
<aura:component controller="TuitionPaymentController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" >

    <aura:attribute name="step" default="1" type="Integer" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="authTransRequest" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="Boolean" default="true" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initialize}"/>  

    <c:TuitionPaymentHeader />
    
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
        <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" />
    </aura:if>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.step==1}">
        <c:TuitionPaymentAmount step="{!v.step}" authTransRequest="{!v.authTransRequest}" />
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.step==2}">
        <c:TuitionPaymentAmount step="{!v.step}" authTransRequest="{!v.authTransRequest}" />
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.step==3}">
        <c:TuitionPaymentCheckout step="{!v.step}" authTransRequest="{!v.authTransRequest}" />
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.step==4}">
        <c:TuitionPaymentConfirmation step="{!v.step}" authTransRequest="{!v.authTransRequest}" />
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.step==5}">
        <c:TuitionPaymentCheck step="{!v.step}" authTransRequest="{!v.authTransRequest}" />
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

```
<aura:component controller="TuitionPaymentController">

    <aura:attribute name="step"  type="Integer" />
    <aura:attribute name="authTransRequest" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="validCourseParticipant" type="Boolean" default="false" />

    <aura:attribute name="showError" type="Boolean" required="true" description="" default="false" access="private"/>
    <aura:attribute name="errorMessage" type="String" description="Error Messages" />

    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">

        <div class="slds-size_1-of-6"></div>

        <div class="slds-size_4-of-6">
            <div class="slds-m-horizontal_medium slds-m-bottom_medium ">
                
                <div class="slds-section slds-is-open">
                    
                    <div class="slds-m-vertical_large">
                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                            Thank you! <br/>
                            Your application has been received. Please mail your deposit today!
                            <br/><br/>
                            -------- more text, deleted for privacy ----------
                            <br/><br/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Unfortunately, I don't think we can help here with the amount of information we have. If there's a button somewhere, then you'll need to find it. I've seen some awful designs where elements are tucked away somewhere and difficult to find. That might be what's going on here. Try searching your codebase for "<lightning-button" and "<button" (without quotes), maybe you'll find something that stands out.

Comment: I imported everything to my VScode and was able to finally find the button, now onto adding the functionality. Thanks!